# upgrade from WSS3 to SPS2010: ErrorWebPart

Tags: web-part, upgrade

So I am doing a trial migrate a site collection from wss3 (with Search Service) to SPS2010 (on a different box). I used a backup copy of the contentdatabase from the wss3 sql server and restore the content database to the SPS2010 sql server.
Before I did the mount-spcontentdatabase on the SPS2010, I had the following Missing Webpart errors report from running test-SPContentDatabase.

> Category        : MissingWebPart Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False Message         : WebPart class
>   [ddbfb079-d77d-89c8-cb82-213960b44379] is referenced [1] times in the
>   database [WSS_Content_IT], but is not installed on the current farm.
>   Please inst
>                     all any feature/solution which contains this web part. Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the
>   database [WSS_Content_XX], but are not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature or solution which conta
>                     ins these web parts.
>
> Category        : MissingWebPart Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False Message         : WebPart class
>   [ab4aa370-2776-5c79-fe24-9018b16861db] is referenced [4] times in the
>   database [WSS_Content_IT], but is not installed on the current farm.
>   Please inst
>                     all any feature/solution which contains this web part. Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the
>   database [WSS_Content_XX], but are not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature or solution which conta
>                     ins these web parts.
>
> Category        : MissingWebPart Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False Message         : WebPart class
>   [a70e5d2b-5a28-f448-159a-41473b653477] is referenced [1] times in the
>   database [WSS_Content_XX], but is not installed on the current farm.
>   Please inst
>                     all any feature/solution which contains this web part. Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the
>   database [WSS_Content_XX], but are not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature or solution which conta
>                     ins these web parts.
>
> Category        : MissingWebPart Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False Message         : WebPart class
>   [dcdbbbd0-8dd6-1ecb-a3b2-12d30061d482] is referenced [164] times in
>   the database [WSS_Content_XX], but is not installed on the current
>   farm. Please in
>                     stall any feature/solution which contains this web part. Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the
>   database [WSS_Content_XX], but are not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature or solution which conta
>                     ins these web parts.
>
> Category        : MissingWebPart Error           : True
>   UpgradeBlocking : False Message         : WebPart class
>   [e6eedeb8-c98b-a1b8-b9ad-21335e8e1b50] is referenced [1] times in the
>   database [WSS_Content_XX], but is not installed on the current farm.
>   Please inst
>                     all any feature/solution which contains this web part. Remedy          : One or more web parts are referenced in the
>   database [WSS_Content_XX], but are not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature or solution which conta
>                     ins these web parts.

I make a notes of all locations where those webparts are.

Since the above erros was not upgradeBlocking error, so I went ahead and did the mount-spcontentdatabase. After this, I then navigated to those locations to check, as expected those webparts were not displaying on page, instead it just said "Web Part Error: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe."
I have then check on the original site collection (the wss3 version), the problematic webparts types are mainly CEWP (DCDBBBD0-8DD6-1ECB-A3B2-12D30061D482), 
AdvancedSearchBox (DDBFB079-D77D-89C8-CB82-213960B44379), 
FederatedResultsWebPart (A70E5D2B-5A28-F448-159A-41473B653477), 
RssFeedReader (AB4AA370-2776-5C79-FE24-9018B16861DB).
I know the RssFeedReader is not OOTB, so fine. I will deal with that later.
Both AdvaniceSearchBox and FederatedResultsWebPart can be recreated later as well.
What really worried me was the CEWP webpart, not only there are almost 200 of those in this site collection, aslo I really couldn't workout why sharepoint couldn't map CEWP webpart to it's correct type on SPS2010.

I left it for a couple of days, when I went back to the upgraded site collection on SPS2010, all of a sudden all the CEWP webparts displayed just fine on all sites. This is really great, I could only assume some sharepoint service which is scheduled to run and fixed the issue.

What I really would like to findout is what could that service be? so when I come to do the real upgrade in production environment, I might be able to  start that service straight away after the upgrade. And ideas?